# OpenFL - Provide time to shader

Tags: glsl, shader, haxe, openfl

I just create a shader and it depends on the current time. My fragment is something like this:

```
varying vec2 vTexCoord;
varying float vAlpha;
uniform sampler2D uImage0;
varying float time;

void main(void)
{
    vec4 color = texture2D(uImage0, SomethingTimeDependant(vTexCoord, time);
    gl_FragColor = color;
    gl_FragColor.rgb *= gl_FragColor.a;
}
```

So to provide the time I used

```
var param: ShaderParameter<Float> = new ShaderParameter<Float>();
param.value = [ getTimer() ];
this.data.time = param;
```

But it only updates when I lost and gain the focus again. Any ideas how to update the time correctly?

Here is the [code of the shader class](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cae1ac9217c574dd75e80c534633474d).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added your `WaveShader` to the bitmap in the DisplayABitmap project from openfl-samples, and couldn't find anything wrong with your code. And indeed, simply changing the bitmap's `x` every frame "fixes" the issue. Internally, this sets `__renderDirty` and some other flags to true, forcing a re-render.

```
Lib.current.stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, function(e:Event) {
   bitmap.x += 0.0001;
});
```

[image]

This suggests OpenFL has some issues with detecting changes to shader parameters. Consider creating an issue on [OpenFL's issue tracker](https://github.com/openfl/openfl/issues).

Btw, the shader seems to expect seconds, not milliseconds (which `getTimer()` returns). You can simply divide by 1000 to get a nice-looking result:

```
this.data.time.value = [ getTimer() / 1000 ];
```

Comment: Excellent... Thank you! I spent all the day with this...  I will create the issue